# Linux command to replace unicode or non ascii characters and also double quotes that are not preceding or following a pipe

Tags: unix, sed, regexp-replace

I have some CSV files that have some string fields encircled by double quotes. The problem is some of those fields are just explanations or comments introduced by people, so there can be a number of non-ASCII (or unicode) characters that my load process won't like and there could be also double quotes in the literal.

I want to remove all non-ASCII characters and some of the double quotes. The delimiter of the file is `|` so I want to remove all double quotes that are not preceding or following a pipe.
I have spent some time looking for a similar question, but all the ones I found were different, so excuse me if I'm asking something already answered.

Example of input file:

```
SEP-23|3958|106xxx|Anonymous Account||IE - IT|000|000000|000|DEFAULT|"TI805 ""¬PID35032 â¿""" AWS Migration""|0000
```

I want a resulting line like this

```
SEP-23|3958|106xxx|Anonymous Account||IE - IT|000|000000|000|DEFAULT|"TI805 PID35032 AWS Migration"|0000
```

I was running a sed command that sometimes does the trick, but I have to run it *x* times to replace all double quotes and it doesn't work in this case, not sure if is because of the non-ASCII characters or something else

```
sed -i 's/\([^|]\)"\([^|]\)/\1\2/g' sample.csv
```

Comment: Use a tool that can correctly parse the flavour of csv your input is encoded in. If your comments can contain arbitrary unicode they can probably also contain `|` and newline characters.

Comment: your sample input appears to be malformed. you have three double-quotes in a row not immediately before or after `|`, and two double-quotes before `|`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this appears to work for your test case.

```
$ sed 's/[^ -~]//g;s/|"/|<|<|</g;s/"|/>|>|>|/g;s/"//g;s/|<|<|</|"/g;s/>|>|>|/"|/g' <<\:
> SEP-23|3958|106xxx|Anonymous Account||IE - IT|000|000000|000|DEFAULT|"TI805 ""¬PID35032 â¿""" AWS Migration""|0000
:
SEP-23|3958|106xxx|Anonymous Account||IE - IT|000|000000|000|DEFAULT|"TI805 PID35032  AWS Migration"|0000
```

Probably don't use `sed -i` until you have a working script (and often not even then). Your attempt doesn't even seem to try to do anything about non-ASCII characters etc.

A proper fix would be to revert the mojibake to useful text, or ideally get the original source to provide the data without mojibake, but often that ship has already sailed, and you have to do what you can with what you already have.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E ':a;s/(\|"[^|]*)[[:punct:]]([^|]*"\|)| ( )/\1\2\3/;ta' <(iconv -c -t ascii input_file)
SEP-23|3958|106xxx|Anonymous Account||IE - IT|000|000000|000|DEFAULT|"TI805 PID35032 AWS Migration"|0000
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/[^\x00-\x7f]//g;s/([^|])"+([^|])/\1\2/g'
```

(delete all non-ASCII characters and all strings of double-quotes between 2 non-`|` characters).

Demo:

```
$ sed -E 's/[^\x00-\x7f]//g;s/([^|])"+([^|])/\1\2/g' <<< 'FOO|"BAR ""¬BAZâ¿"""|'
FOO|"BAR BAZ"|
```